# Creating a mail rule programatically or with certain syntax

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I want to create an Outlook mail rule for every company that I deal with so that @xyzcompany.com goes to xyz company folder and @abccompany.com goes to abcompany etc.. without creating a rule for each one.

It would have to create folders for new companies that I haven't dealt with.

If anyone has any ideas I would be most grateful.

Comment: Are you connecting to an Exchange server to get your email?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 does that matter?

Comment: @LChip Yes, because server-side rules can be programmatically created at the Exchange server, or via EWS. I guess maybe I should have immediate suffixed it with "Do you have access to it?" :)

Comment: I am using an exchange server. I am not sure why it would matter.

Comment: @RogerHills Do you have (admin) access to your Exchange server?

Comment: nope its on 365 unfortunately

Comment: @RogerHills do you have admin access to the Office365 environment? A lot can be done with powershell.

Comment: Sorry didn't see this I dont but my colleague does. So if I google for powershell and 365 I might see something.